# How to copy paste values between Input sheet and workbook

Tags: excel, vba

What I want to do:

1. open input sheet
2. open output sheet
3. Click on Button to copy/transfers values `A1:A10` & `B1:B10` from Input sheet to Workbook

now the big problem:

4. the workbook has the actual file name stored in `C1` aka `Input sheet.xls`

Now how do I tell VBA to read cell `C1` so it knows what my Input sheet name is?

So far I found a option that only works if I manually change the file name in VBA

```
Sub transfervalues()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Input Sheet.xls")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("COPY")

Set wb2 = Workbooks("Workbook.xls")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("PASTE")

ws2.Range("A1:A10").Value = ws1.Range("A1:A10").Value
ws2.Range("B1:B10").Value = ws1.Range("B1:B10").Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the cell C1 is in the activesheet.

Try this:

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks(ActiveSheet.Range("C1"))
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Should be obvious that it is located in `ws2`. Try to offer something like `Set ws1 = Workbooks(ws2.Range("C1").Value).Sheets("COPY")` and according to this, it would be better to set the target (`wb2`/`ws2`) first. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the Tip, it definitely guided me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help, after a little trial and error I got it to work. This is how the code looks like:

```
Sub transfervalues()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet



Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Input Sheet")

Set wb1 = Workbooks(ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value)
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Output Sheet")

ws2.Range("A1:A10").Value = ws1.Range("A1:A10").Value
ws2.Range("B1:B10").Value = ws1.Range("B1:B10").Value

End Sub
```